# Appearance menu options in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in word press theme designing. I have created a new theme, but in appearance menu it shows only

- Themes
- Widgets
- Editor

Like the pre-built wp themes (twentyten and twentyelevan), I want all other menu options.

- Themes
- Widgets
- Menus
- Theme Options
- Header
- Background
- Editor

I make search on google and found only about how to add menu option, but didnèt find the solution for other options. Please help me and tell me its solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**

for Custom Background: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds

you need to add theme supports

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support

for widgets http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Actually play around with twentyten or **twentyeleven** and you'll see the codes in there.
most are in the functions.php, then sidebar.php

Happy Coding :)

---

Are you sure you're currently logged user is an Administrator?

if yes, maybe there are some codes in your functions.php, or other php files, or some plugins are disabling those options.

Canyou check if there are any codes like this

```
remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'theme_options');
```

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

Comment: no I have created that theme by myself. That's why I don't know how to enable these options.